# Docker container with SSH does not run with --user flag

Tags: docker, ssh

I have a `Dockerfile` which builds with open_ssh. I want to run the container with a non-root user to grant files/folders with all the permissions automatically by default for that specific user.

If I run the image as follows:

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) <name>:<tag>
```

the container doesn't start. I checked the logs and it says `sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.`

However, if I remove the `--user` flag it works as expected.

I am guessing it is because in the `Dockerfile` I am only giving access to root user

```
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Is there any option to be able to run the container with any user apart from root?